# Select all cells on UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to have an edit button select all the cells on a table. I've been trying to figure out what I am doing wrong. Here is my code. I am basically looping through the sections and then through the number of rows. Whatever I do, it does not setSelect each cell. How would I achieve this?

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *caseDataTableView;

@synthesize segmentControl,caseDataTableView,IndicationView,procedureView,indicationScrollView,procedureScrollView,segmentControllView,segmentControllios6;


- (IBAction)editButtonTapped:(id)sender {

    for (int i = 0; i < self.caseDataTableView.numberOfSections; i++) {
        for (NSInteger r = 0; r < [self.caseDataTableView numberOfRowsInSection:i]; r++) {
             UITableViewCell *cell = [self.caseDataTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:r inSection:i]];
             [cell setSelected:YES];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What method is the code you have shown located in?  Its hard to tell what is going on without more detail.

Comment: Good point. I'll add that.

Comment: Do you have the IBAction wired up properly?  Like are you sure that code is executing when the button is pressed?

Comment: Yeah, I've ran NSLog statements to ensure that is happening. I've been doing this on a simulator btw.

Comment: When you say you want them selected you mean you want them to have a checkmark?

Comment: I would like them to look like when I individually click the text boxes to edit them. It has a surrounding box when clicked to edit. Right now it doesn't have that unless I manually click.

Comment: why not use `-didSelectRowAtIndexPath` instead of `-cellForRowAtIndexPath `? it would be something like `[self tableView:YOURTABLE didSelectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:r inSection:i]];`

Comment: Can you show code for config `Cell`? What is state of cell is selected? If have it I can help you.

Comment: @0yeoj Good question. I will give this a shot.

Comment: @vienvu I added the proper code that creates the supporting class for the cell. Is that what you wanted? Forgive me as I am getting my feet wet with iOS development if this not what you are looking for.

Comment: @0yeoj When you refer to YOURTABLE, could you please specify more?

Comment: @wowzuzz, that is your `self.caseDataTableView`

Comment: I'm getting an error with this code.

UITableViewCell *celltwo = [self tableView:caseDataTableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:r inSection:i]];

Comment: Initializing UITableViewCell *_strong with an expression of incompatible type void.

Comment: @wowzuzz, no need for assignment, also remove `[cell setSelected:YES];`

Comment: Wow, thanks I'll give this a shot.

Comment: I get this tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7db53400' on my console.

Comment: [self tableView:caseDataTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:r inSection:i]];

This is now giving me editable labels but it scrolls to the bottom. I want it to stay at the top.

Comment: Another thing too. On the loop it selects every cell, until the last one on the loop. I want to select every label at the same time.

Comment: @wowzuzz,  i see... and setting the cell as selected using `[cell setSelected:YES];`, you should have pointed that in your question, anyway i think that approach doesn't suits your implementation... maybe using separate `array` containing all the selectedIndexes will be better.. i'll post an answer later.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that I had was two things. The first being the editButtonTapped method being incorrect.

```
- (IBAction)editButtonTapped:(id)sender {

for (int i = 0; i < self.caseDataTableView.numberOfSections; i++) {
    for (NSInteger r = 0; r < [self.caseDataTableView numberOfRowsInSection:i]; r++) {
        [self tableView:caseDataTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:r inSection:i]];
    }
}}
```

The next issue was the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method scrolling down when I would do my loop. It would eventually go down to the last cell in the previous loop. I took this piece of code out on the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method.

```
[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES]
```

Setting the scrollPosition in my situation would clear the selections out and thats why it was removed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a for loop

```
- (IBAction)editButtonTapped:(id)sender 
{
   for (int i = 0; i < self.tableView.numberOfSections; i++) 
   {
       for (int j = 0; j < [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:i]; j++)    
       {
        [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:j inSection:i]
                                    animated:NO
                              scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select a cell calling table view's selectRowAtIndexPath method:

```
[caseDataTableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop];
```